# Mongoose async/ await correct method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I'm new to mongoose and node could anyone please point out which is the right method, my intention is to send the list of all products in my MongoDB to client.

method 1

```
 items = await Product.findById({})
.then((items) => {
  if (items == null) {
    res.status(404).send("no items");
  } else {
    res.send(items);
    next();
  }
})
.catch((err) => {
  res.status(404).send({ error: err });
});
```

method 2

```
items = await Product.find({}).exec();
  res.status(200).send(items)
  next();
```

Also could you point out how can i use again one more await call if i have to process items and send after that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 2 should looks like that:

```
router.get('/:param', async function(req, res) {
    try {
        let items = await Product.find({}).lean()
        res.status(200).json(items);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).json(e);
    }
});
```

1. You don't need `.exec()`
2. You need to use `.lean()` if you want to receive js object in items, not mongoose's.
3. Try not to request all docs collection at once, especially if collection have more then 1000+ documents. Otherwise do it via `.cursor` or `limit(Number)` to avoid problems with DB.

Also as already mentioned above, try to use `async/await` and ES6 syntax. It's just looks better.

And please, mark question as answered, just to avoid your question to be flagged.